# Absolute Positioned Floating Header Jitters in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, animation, safari

I have a simple JSFiddle of a single floating header here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zT9KQ/

Basically, this uses `translate3d` to kick in the GPU and hardware accelerate the floating header so that it may be drawn more smoothly. The header jitters in the latest Safari but gets drawn perfectly fine in the latest Chrome, FF and Opera. The actual code that is being affected by this (the code that spurred this question) is code I've written that cannot be shared publicly but works in a similar manner where `fixed` positioning is, unfortunately, not a valid solution.

I have tried:

1. Setting the `backface-visibility` CSS property to `none`.
2. Setting the `perspective` CSS property to `1000`.
3. Playing with `requestAnimationFrame` during the animation logic.
4. Throttling the scroll event callback.
5. Setting the `translateZ` transform to something higher than `0px`.

But none of this has worked (or at least - it seems reasonable to assume the GPU has kicked in but the jittering persists). I noticed that two questions are already open that are identical this one I'm raising but no one has answered them:

- [Jitter in Sticky Header in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546270/jitter-in-sticky-header-in-safari)
- [Implementing fixed position in javascript causes jitter in Safari when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546411/implementing-fixed-position-in-javascript-causes-jitter-in-safari-when-scrolling)

Is this a known bug? Is there a performance hole I'm not sealing up?

**EDIT**

I have been receiving a lot of questions as to why `position: fixed` is not a valid option. To directly reply to Antony's comment on the question itself:

I'm not emulating/reinventing `position: fixed`. If you look at the top-voted answer (as of this comment), you will see that this seems to be a Safari issue. The reason `position: fixed` is undesirable in this case is because the code in question must be able to support multiple floating headers that sit below each other and have a "container" range where there may be infinitely nested containers. Using fixed positioning not only makes the code more complicated in the case where these floating headers live in a container that horizontally scrolls but also makes the component more brittle overall (calculating offsets when the widget needs to sit within another container somewhere else on the page). So, semantically, `absolute` positioning fits my needs better than `fixed`.

**SECOND EDIT**

Upon thinking about what Antony had been telling me (that I may be reinventing the wheel), and after hearing about `-wekbit-sticky` from user3716477, I would like to update the question to show what I'm trying to do. You can see how my code behaves in every browser other than Safari here:

http://cl.ly/3y1i3C473G2G

I have learned:

1. You cannot rely on the `scroll` or really any scroll-like events (such as `mousewheel`) since they are asynchronous in nature. I submitted a bug to Apple detailing what was happening and they closed the bug for this reason.
2. There is no real way to do what I want as of now - to have multiple floating headers that stack and replace each other. I guess I'll have to wait for something like [`-webkit-sticky`](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit) to come out.
3. I should include *all* relevant information in SO questions from here on out. :-P

Thanks for playing guys! Here's the exact response I received from Apple:

> Apple Developer Relations09-Jun-2014 01:16 PM
>
> Engineering has determined that there are no plans to address this
>   based on the following:
>
> Code is using scroll events, which are asynchronous.
>
> We are now closing this bug report.
>
> If you have questions regarding the resolution of this issue, please
>   update your bug report with that information.
>
> Please be sure to regularly check new Apple releases for any updates
>   that might affect this issue.

Comment: Try reading this article, http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

Comment: ^ @bodi0 what am I looking for? I read through the article, but it doesn't explain anything that seems relevant to me. I have already hardware accelerated the elements that need to be hardware accelerated and am not looking for a fallback, but thanks for the link.

Comment: Indeed Safari browser has problems with `translate3d` transform and fixed position, I confirm that, you *may* need a fallback after all...

Comment: ...in fact, my Safari (v. 5,1,7) crashed every time when I tried to visit the jsfiddle page with your example and the other pages in your question...

Comment: How do you want this to travel? Will it be used at the top of the page or at the top of some other container on page? It would help if I knew what you are trying to accomplish in a big picture sort of way. I just did a few similar sticky element type jobs recently.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by emulating `position: fixed` with `position: absolute`? You are definitely going to take some performance penalty by attaching to a scroll event instead of the much simpler way of telling the element to stay fixed. What is the limitation of `position: fixed` that makes you reinvent the wheel? Beware, you might be a victim of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Antony please check my edit to the question. I did not know about the XY problem, but thank you for bringing it up. I'm sure it will be handy to address other cognitive biases I may have. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since there is an [apparent delay](http://jsfiddle.net/AJj56/) between scrolling with the trackpad and the `scroll` event firing, you can attach the handler to an additional [`mousewheel` event](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html) to smoothen things up.

```
$scrollContainer.on('scroll mousewheel', function () {
    // reinvent the wheel here
});
```

You can see in [this demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5SFY/) that jittering is far less likely to occur when you scroll with the trackpad. In the demo, I have invoked the handler on load to eliminate the flash when you first scroll on Safari. There may still be some occasional jitter, but if you want to minimize that, you can go the resource intensive way of [using `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame`](http://jsfiddle.net/M2zvu/).

This might fix the problem for now, but as I have said before, this emulation approach is not ideal and you are very likely to run into more trouble down the road.

Comment: Awesome! So does this mean that the code path (within Safari itself) hit by dragging the scroll bar is the same code path that's fired when the `mousewheel` event fires? Also, when you mention "this emulation approach", what are you referring to? The fixed positioning vs. absolute positioning (because that's the only thing you mentioned before) or the use of mousewheel? I've already explained why absolute positioning makes more sense, and this has offered me a solution (which is why I've upvoted this answer), but it does not provide me an explanation. Still seems to be a Safari bug.

Comment: Dragging the scrollbar does not fire `mousewheel`, it only fires `scroll`. But the 2-finger swipe fires both. The reason why there is a problem on Safari is that when you scroll with the trackpad, the `scroll` event doesn't fire for at least 10 ms. The content has moved but the handler doesn't run, causing the jitter. The reason why `mousewheel` works is because it fires as soon as you swipe. If you compare this to Chrome, for example, you can see that `scroll` fires 0 - 1 ms after `mousewheel`, which allows the handler to run almost immediately.

Comment: You can call this a bug, but I doubt they are going to fix that 10 ms delay for an edge case like this when someone wants to roll their own version of `position: fixed`. I have read your explanation, but you haven't explained enough to be honest. How does `position: absolute` help with calculating offset when both `absolute` and `fixed` takes the element out of the flow? If I were to approach this problem, I would take the headers out and give them `position: relative`. You can calculate offset however you want. But since you didn't get to the real issue, I can only offer this workaround.

Comment: Yes, `position: absolute` takes the element out of the flow, but it does so *relative to the containing parent*, which is the desired functionality here since the parents define the floating range (so to speak). We could do this with `position: fixed`, but it wouldn't actually semantically be correct since fixed position elements are taken out of the flow and positioned *relative to the viewport*.

Comment: I wish I could give you the concrete example of code I'm working with, and I will definitely ping you once I open source it, but, as of now, I can't since my company owns it. :-P Also, this workaround does not work with multiple floating headers (as you hinted at - it's not a real solution - it's a workaround), but I definitely appreciate you looking into this! In the meantime, I'm waiting to hear back from Apple.

Comment: At least you can give me a fiddle of multiple floating headers. I don't need a concrete example but a **minimal** example that can reflect the problem you are having (i.e. eliminating jitter and retaining ability of calculating offset), which can look completely different from the proprietary code. I guess your company does not *own* multiple floating headers, or many of us will be in big trouble. The point is your example does not demonstrate the problem you are having and you're hindering yourself from getting a proper solution to your problem.

Comment: Finally I can get to see the real issue. If all you need is multiple levels of sticky headers, and calculating offset is only used in that context, then you can eliminate `fixed` positioning altogether. This is how I would approach the problem: No infinitely nested containers. Just a simple container with multiple headers. Clone the headers and take them out of the flow. Use `position: absolute` to let the stick to the outer container. Let them reenter the flow when other headers reach the stick position. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kd4mP/). Feel free to change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Hmmm the elements seem to flash in that on Chrome 35.0.1916.114. Yes that's the official issue. Sorry it took so long to get to the point where you saw something (check the third point in the lessons learned section in my edit).

Comment: [I have fixed the flash](http://jsfiddle.net/kd4mP/2/). It's not meant to be the final solution but a demonstration of how you can approach the problem. I suggest you take a look at the code and see how things could be done differently. Just rely less on `scroll` to handle the position of the elements and let CSS do its job. This is a classic example of the XY problem. You could have saved yourself a lot of trouble if you can tell us the actual problem in the first place.

Comment: Ah that looks much better (although not 100% smooth in Safari - it looks really good). BTW, if you couldn't tell, I understand your point on the XY problem and apologize. As someone who has just admitted fault, here is my advice for you: __Learn how to stop driving a point when someone has apologized and admitted fault.__ It will burn a lot of bridges for you in the future (from personal experience), and you'll burn bridges with the best kind of people (the kind who are willing to say they messed up). Just my two cents. Leaving it for you since you seem like a smart guy.

Comment: For future readers of this post, [`mousewheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event) is now deprecated, use the [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) event instead

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a bug with Safari scrolling. If you drag the scrollbar manually (don't use the trackpad gesture to scroll), then there is no jittering.

Chrome (and other browsers) handle scrolling differently which is why this bug is only present on Safari. You might want to submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: In light of this information, it does indeed appear to be a bug with Safari. I have submitted an issue to Apple. I'll keep the question open for a few more days to see what other things people may see, but I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: Still jitters when manually dragging the scrollbars on Mac 10.9.3/Safari 7.0.4

Comment: @OnurYıldırım thanks for the update. I have updated my Apple Radar bug report.

Answer (score 1):

How about a little restructuring, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/zT9KQ/6/

html:

```
<div>
<h1>Header</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.content {
    height:1000px;
}
h1 {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, was having a problem where a  fixed element was moving up and down all jittery on scroll, after trying other solutions like `transform: translateZ(0);` and `overflow-y:scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` neither of which worked the solution was to move that element outside of the parent element which was also fixed. Thanks for pointing me on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something similar to the jiddle code you have to check if browser is safari and then make it a different way like:

```
$(function () {
    var $header = $('h1'),
        $container = $('.container'),
        $scrollContainer = $('.scroll-container'),
        scrollContainerOffset = $scrollContainer.offset().top;
    $scrollContainer.on('scroll', function () {
        var top = Math.max(0, $container.offset().top * -1 + scrollContainerOffset);
        $header.css('top', top + 'px');

    });
});
```

Even when it isn't the way you want your problem to be solved, it might be a workaround that may help...

Answer (score 0):

Scroll events are sent asynchronously in various browsers; you should not rely on them to do things like this.

The best solution would be to use position:-webkit-sticky; top: 0;

Comment: You may be correct about it not being the best thing to rely on asynchronous events like scroll, but what is `-webkit-sticky` positioning? I can't find anything on that property.

Comment: @Vinay [`-webkit-sticky`](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit) is a new type of positioning for sticky headers that behaves mostly like `fixed`, but will scroll once they are out of bounds, which is originally introduced on iOS. I have been wondering if you are trying to achieve something like this, but couldn't confirm based on the limited info you have given. When I say you might be reinventing the wheel, this is one of the many possible scenarios.

Comment: @Antony good point. Yes this seems similar to something I'm trying to do (multiple floating headers that stick).

Answer (score 0):

You could try and disable all and any javascript-ish scroll handling and just simply remove

`position: relative;` from the `.container`.

Afterwards just add `h1{ top:0; }` and it will happily stick to the `.scroll-container`.

Excerpt from CSS absolute positioning:

> Position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor...

To explain - your absolute H1 will look up the tree for the first ancestor element which defines a "position" property and inherit it as a 0,0 reference point.

It could be a WTF at first, but this behaviour is a powerhouse once you tame it.

EDIT: Related to the original jsFiddle, I made some more property removals:

http://jsfiddle.net/253Ss/

^ `.container` wrapper could be removed as well, since it is no more neccessary in a technical sense.

Comment: The only issue is that the `.container` bounds where the sticky header will float. That is, I am trying to float within the `.container` and not relative to the `.scroll-container`.