# Glitch with css and webkit when changing background on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with this sticky header on a site I'm currently developing. I made the sticky changes on scroll using jquery, here is the code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){       
    var scroll_pos = 0;
    jQuery(document).scroll(function() { 
        if(jQuery(window).width()>990){ 
            scroll_pos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
            if(scroll_pos > 10){ 
            if(!jQuery('#header_super_wrapper').hasClass('fixed_header')){
                jQuery('#header_super_wrapper').addClass('fixed_header');
            }
            if(jQuery("#logo > a > img").hasClass("standard")){
                jQuery("#logo > a > img").attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/scrollNavLogoSmall.png");
            }
        } else {
            if(jQuery('#header_super_wrapper').hasClass('fixed_header')){
                jQuery('#header_super_wrapper').removeClass('fixed_header');
            }
            if(jQuery("#logo > a > img").hasClass("standard")){
                jQuery("#logo > a > img").attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/logo_1_small.png");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the css

```
.fixed_header{
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaaaaa;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaaaaa;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top:0px;
    display: block;
}

.fixed_header nav .menu > li.menu-item > a{
    color:#25aae1;
}
```

Everything works just fine on Mozilla and Firefox but when I'm on webkit (Chrome - Safari) I see a lot of glitches.
The test url of the site is
http://www.innovativedentallabs.com.php53-7.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/

Someone suugested to add -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) to the code, but this doesn't work.

I'm planning to clean up and add those changes into css classes, but first I need to fix this issue.

Any help from the experts will be really appreciated.

Forgive my bad english

Comment: Just use CSS [`position:fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) instead of JavaScript. Add/remove a class with JavaScript if necessary, but let `position:fixed` do the rest of the work.

Comment: Thanks @Blazemonger I've tried that, but it has the same results. Edited the question to update the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute Positioned Floating Header Jitters in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990069/absolute-positioned-floating-header-jitters-in-safari)

Comment: @Nit I've already read that question and it's answers, the problem is no related with the event starter (mouse, scroll bar, downkey), it's a general problem when scrolling in the webkit browsers and the fixed position. Also I tried some of those solutions and none of those worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a Workaround, might not be the best approach but it works.

Instead of using fixed positioning, I calculate the element's top value using jQuery on scroll.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if(scroll_pos > 10) {                       
        jQuery('#header_super_wrapper').css('top', scroll_pos);
    } else {
        jQuery('#header_super_wrapper').css('top', 0);
    }
});
```

And that's pretty much it.

I hope someone will have a css solution for this issue.