# Relative positioned div jitters while scrolling in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the following fiddle, there is significant jitter while scrolling. The jitter is noticed only in Safari on Mac, while Chrome and Firefox scrolls the page smoothly.

https://jsfiddle.net/saptarshi17/akxuLL9x/

The jitter is a result of applying parallax effect on the first paragraph. The parallax is implemented by dynamically calculating the `top` css property triggered by `scroll` events. I am noticing this on Mac OSX El Capitan, not sure about Windows.

So far, I tried:

1. Added a `mousewheel` event-listener in addition to `scroll` as per [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23990069/absolute-positioned-floating-header-jitters-in-safari?answertab=active#tab-top) on SO.
2. Tried wrapping the `css("top", ...)` function call within `requestAnimationFrame()`
3. Changed div from `relative` to `absolute` to avoid costly reflows.
4. Added `preserve3d` property to "hardware accelerate" position calculation as per some comments somewhere on SO.

Since 2 and 3 haven't helped, I assume the core issue has much to do with Safari's scroll implementation and less about frame-rate optimizations. There is a delay Safari's predictive rendering and the subsequent handler call which offsets the position. This results in 2 renders causing the jitter. While I understand Safari's intention behind the first render which works in most cases, this seems to be wrong in cases when the developer wants to override positioning. Maybe there is a way to tell Safari to disable the predictive rendering.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `the first div scrolls slower than the rest of the page.` if it's what I think it is, I'm having the issue on Chrome as well.

Comment: I meant it's parallax. It's intentional. The issue is that this scroll movement is smooth in Chrome but jittery in Safari. Let me rephrase that part of my question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Have you tried applying will-change to the div?

Comment: @Pat Seems 'will-change' is not supported in Safari as per https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=will-change shows safari 9.1/10 supporting it. Worth giving it a shot.

Comment: @Pat No luck with `will-change` either. Care to double-check the forked fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/saptarshi17/judsf56s to make sure I have used it correctly?

Comment: Which version of safari are you on? I tried your jsfiddle on my mac (I had to use vanilla js because my certificates are messed up so I can't load jquery) and it seems fine. Does this work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/akxuLL9x/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122134/discussion-between-s-b-and-pat).